# How to Check All ASP CheckBoxList items using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Can you please help me.

I have an ASP RadioButtonList with two list items; Select All and UnSelect All.

[Radio Button List to select all or unselect all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Li8n.png)

I also have an ASP CheckBoxList that is database bound. 
I need to check all items on the check box when the Select All button is selected and unselect all if the Unselect All is selected.

I am using javascript.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var select = $(".radio-set").find("input:checked").val();

        $('#<%=rdSelectContractor.ClientID %>').change(function () {

            if (select = "0") {

                $('.check_set_contractor').each(function () {

                    $(this).closest('table').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
                });
            }

            else if (select = "1") {

                $('.check_set_contractor').each(function () {

                    $(this).closest('table').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

### My RadioButtonList

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdSelectContractor" runat="server" CssClass="radio-set">
          <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select All</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="1">UnSelect All</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

### My CheckBoxList

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ContractorId" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="6" CssClass="check_set_contractor"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Thank you so much

Comment: You missed "==" in your code and used "=".

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to handle change event of your radio button like below :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="rdSelectContractor"]').change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var allCheckBoxes = $('.check_set_contractor');
    if (selectedValue == 0) {
      allCheckBoxes.prop("checked", true);
    } else if (selectedValue == 1) {
      allCheckBoxes.prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What about `allCheckBoxes.prop("checked", selectedValue == 0);` instead of the if/else if?

Answer (score 0):

I see few issues with your code, you are relying on `.radio-set` class which asp.net server control renders as html applies to the html table, this may produce unexpected results. Next, you are looping through the table which is wrappend around your checkboxlist.

Instead you can do it like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="rdSelectContractor"]').change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        var ContractorIdCheckbox = $('input[name^="ContractorId"]');
        if (selectedValue == 0) {
             ContractorIdCheckbox.prop("checked", true);
        }
        else if (selectedValue == 1) {
             ContractorIdCheckbox.prop("checked", false);
        }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think basic structure of your code is little messy.

Also you forgot to add `COMPARISION OPERATOR '=='` and used `'='`

Also you need to check for `true/false` if radio button is `checked/unchecked`, not needed its value, so dont use `.val()`

Based on your problem, I have provided a fiddle that is working according to your need.

Because of unavailability of ASP.NET controls on jsfiddle, I have assumed sample controls, but you can easily change IDs and classes as per your ASP.NET requirements.

You can make it short and sweet as per my fiddle.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/b5qu92cf/9/)